# SP 2013 - What is the correct syntax to add the results of 2 or more If statements?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, if-statement

I want to create a "scorecard" where the user simply selects "yes" or "no" for each field in the list. Then, I want to assign a point value to "yes" or "no values and add the point values together in a calculated field call Total.

"No" values are always zero (0). Here is one of my many iterations - which all fail:
=(IF([CEU Completion QTR 1]="yes",5,0))+
    (IF([CEU Completion QTR 2]="yes",5,0))

The [CEU Completion QTR 1] and [CEU Completion QTR 2] fields are Yes/No (checkbox) fields. There are other fields but resolving these will clue me in on how to add the other fields. I know there is a limit of 7 nested fields. I have 14 fields I need to assign a point value to and add together for a grand total so I need to avoid more than 7 nested If statements - advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a trick that you can use to calculate this elegantly. It is based on the fact that boolean values (Yes/No) can be used in numeric calculations and their values are treated as 1 for Yes and 0 for No.

So you could create a calculated column, set it's data type to `number` and use this as the formula:

```
[CEU Completion QTR 1]*5 + [CEU Completion QTR 2]*5
```

You could also add the other fields to the formula and calculate the total value.

Comment: That worked very well! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the fileds are Yes/No (checkbox) fields, you need to just create the caluculated column like this:

```
=(IF([CEU Completion QTR 1],5,0))+(IF([CEU Completion QTR 2],5,0))
```